# looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, xml, exception, soap, limit

I'm having some strange problem while using SOAP with PHP.
Same function works with small data, but when my query returns more than X rows, it causes an exception "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document".

This is my code:

```
<?php
$cliente = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => $myserver,'uri' => 'urn:webservices'));
?>
<select id="actividad" name="actividad" size="1" style="height:40px; width: 100%;">
<?php
$acs = $cliente->get_actividades();
foreach($acs as $actividad) {
echo "<option value='".$actividad['idactividad']."'>".$actividad['descripcion']."</option>";
}                                       
?>
</select>
```

And this is server side:

```
public function get_actividades()
{
    $link = new mysqli($this->dbhost,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass,$this->dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        return 0;
    }
    $query = "SELECT idactividad, codigo, descripcion FROM actividades";
    $datos = array();
    if ($stmt = $link->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $datos = $this->fetcharray($stmt);
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $datos;
    } else { 
        return -1; 
    }           
}
```

That query results in about 37 rows. If I add a "LIMIT" clause to that query between 1 and 21 rows, it works fine, but more than that causes the no-xml-exception.

Can it be some memory problem?? Who could i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a value like you did you must echo it. If for instance you echoed `$datos` it will still not work because you need to display a SOAP-compliant XML document. You need to process that array of rows to turn them into a XML document.

Answer (score 0):

A byte order mark (BOM) would have the same effect as whitespace before the php tags. Here you find a PHP snippet to detect and remove a BOM. Be sure to configure you editor to not insert the BOM again.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20100501135607/http://www.dotvoid.com/2010/04/detecting-utf-bom-byte-order-mark/